how to make diamond shape author list for acm conference format
The default (two authors per line) looks like the following:

Because the first author has more affiliations which makes the first row of authors looks quite imbalanced. I am. thinking about is there a way we can make the author list a diamond shape like below:
I have played with the parameter authorsperrow a little bit which does not seem to help. Because it always put the same number of authors on each line. Here is the MWE I have tried. We would appreciate if anyone can provide any suggestions.
\documentclass[sigconf,screen,nonacm]{acmart}
\settopmatter{printfolios=true, printccs=false, printacmref=false,authorsperrow=2}



\begin{document}
\title{This is the Title}

\author{Author1}
\affiliation{
  \department{Computer Science and Engineering}
  \institution{A University}    
  \country{China}\\
  \department{Department of Computer Science}  
    \institution{B University}%% \institution is required
    \country{US}}
\email{email@uni.edu}          %% \email is recommended

\author{Author2}
\affiliation{%
    \institution{A University}
    \country{US}}
\email{email@uni.edu}          %% \email is recommended

\author{Author3}
\affiliation{
    \institution{B University}
    \country{USA}}
\email{email@uni.edu}          %% \email is recommended

\author{Author4}
\affiliation{
  \institution{AResearch}            %% \institution is required
  \country{USA}    
}
\email{email@uni.edu}          %% \email is recommended


\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
\endinput


Unrelated but why do you have \endinput after \end{document} (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23102/endinput-what-is-it-for)?

And slightly related: your proposed layout needs more space than the original, so if you have a page limit for your paper then you will regret this choice :)

@Marijn the paper is already accepted, and we don't mind paying a few hundred bucks for the extra page. Thank you for the reminder anyway.
